# show validation for my login form if no already exist in backend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive

I'm using a directive for populating my front-end with validation if the number is already present in back-end but it shows validation for every number, whether it's present in back-end or not.

Below is a code sample:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <md-input-container>
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="assets/images/device.svg"></md-icon>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter user mobile no" name=mobile" id="mobile" ng-model="mobile" required minlength="10"  ng-pattern="/^[789]\d{9}$/" phone-number-validator>
        <div ng-messages="myForm.mobile.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">Registered mobile no.</div>
            <div ng-message="phoneNumber">The mobile No entered has already been registered</div>
            <div ng-message="test">too short</div>
       </div>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('shoppingPad').directive('phoneNumberValidator',phoneNumberValidator)


function phoneNumberValidator($q,loginServices,restService){
    var deferred=$q.defer();
    return{
        restrict:'EA',
        require:'ngModel',

        link:function($scope,element,attrs,ngModel){
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.phoneNumber=function(modelValue , viewValue) {

                var mobile= (modelValue || viewValue).toString();
                    console.log(typeof mobile);
                    if(mobile.length == 10){

                        console.log('mobile 2' + typeof loginServices.getMobileNo());

                        return restService.getRequest('save/all?m='+mobile).then(function(response){
                            console.log("inside rest");
                            deferred.reject(response.status);
                            return deferred.promise;


                        },function(error){

                            return deferred.promise;
                        });

                    }

            }
        }


    }

}
```

**Service**

```
angular.module('shoppingPad').service('restService',restService);

function restService($http){
    var port=4005;
    var baseUrl="http://localhost:"+port;

    this.getRequest=function(path,query){
        console.log("we are in the getRequest");
        var def=$http.get(baseUrl+"/"+path,query);
        console.log(def)
        return def;
    };
}

 nodejs
router.get('/all',function(req,res){
console.log("abcd");
var mobile=(req.query.m)

console.log(typeof mobile);
console.log(mobile)
user.all(mobile,function(error,data){
    if(error){
        res.send(error)
    }else{
        res.send(data)
    }
})
```

});

UserList.prototype.all=function(mobile,cb){

```
User.find({mobile:mobile},function(err,data){
    if(data){
        console.log(data);
        return cb(null,data)
    }
   else{
        return cb(err,null);
    }
});
```

};

Comment: where do you pass in your model  id for different result? What I see is that you use the same url and arguments for all your models...

Comment: in my nodejs code i'm matching the mobile number passed from front end to the one existing in database.if the no exists in database it would show validation otherwise not

Comment: i'm not using model id the validation should be based on unique mobile no

Comment: okay, what's the difference between then loginServices.getMobileNo() and mobile ??

Comment: ok, stupid question please ignore it

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Figured it out.

You need to create the promise inside of the asyncValidator otherwise you will be only doing one validation for all the *ngModel*s.

The second mistake is returning the request's promise which will be always resolved/rejected by $http service.

```
angular.module('shoppingPad').directive('phoneNumberValidator', phoneNumberValidator)


function phoneNumberValidator($q, loginServices, restService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: 'ngModel',

        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.phoneNumber = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                var mobile = (modelValue || viewValue).toString();
                if (mobile.length === 10) {
                    restService.getRequest('save/all?m=' + mobile).then(function (response) {
                        if (response.status === 'mobile already exist') {
                            deferred.reject(response.status)
                        }
                        else {
                            deferred.resolve();
                        }

                    }, function (error) {
                        //todo reject or resolve 
                        return deferred.promise;
                    });

                } else {
                    //no validation error if length is not 10
                    deferred.resolve();
                }
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: just a fill in for switching on that the mobile is exist or not, you always return a response from the server even if does not exist, right?

Comment: i have added my nodejs code also please review it and tell me where i'm going wrong

Comment: can you include the cb call too??